# How to define user input for language translator trained model

Tags: python

Please house I am new in nmt, I did hard coding of a model to translate English to my dialect. The model have worked perfectly but I am having trouble defining user input for actual translation to the model. Blow is the src of the model evaluation. Your assistance will be really appreciated.

`

```
# load a clean dataset
def load_clean_sentences(filename):
    return load(open(filename, 'rb'))
 
# load datasets
dataset = load_clean_sentences('english-tiv-both.pkl')
train = load_clean_sentences('english-tiv-train.pkl')
test = load_clean_sentences('english-tiv-test.pkl')

# fit a tokenizer
def create_tokenizer(lines):
    tokenizer = Tokenizer()
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(lines)
    return tokenizer

# max sentence length
def max_length(lines):
    return max(len(line.split()) for line in lines)
# prepare english tokenizer
eng_tokenizer = create_tokenizer(dataset[:, 0])
eng_vocab_size = len(eng_tokenizer.word_index) + 1
eng_length = max_length(dataset[:, 0])

# prepare tiv tokenizer
tiv_tokenizer = create_tokenizer(dataset[:, 1])
tiv_vocab_size = len(tiv_tokenizer.word_index) + 1
tiv_length = max_length(dataset[:, 1])

## encode and pad sequences
def encode_sequences(tokenizer, length, lines):
    # integer encode sequences
    X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(lines)
    # pad sequences with 0 values
    X = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=length, padding='post')
    return X

## one hot encode target sequence
def encode_output(sequences, vocab_size):
    ylist = list()
    for sequence in sequences:
        encoded = to_categorical(sequence, num_classes=vocab_size)
        ylist.append(encoded)
    y = array(ylist)

# prepare data
trainX = encode_sequences(tiv_tokenizer, tiv_length, train[:, 1])
testX = encode_sequences(tiv_tokenizer, tiv_length, test[:, 1])

# load model
model = load_model('model.h5')
# map an integer to a word
def word_for_id(integer, tokenizer):
    for word, index in tokenizer.word_index.items():
        if index == integer:
            return word
    return None

# generate target given source sequence
def predict_sequence(model, tokenizer, source):
    prediction = model.predict(source, verbose=0)[0]
    integers = [argmax(vector) for vector in prediction]
    target = list()
    for i in integers:
        word = word_for_id(i, tokenizer)
        if word is None:
            break
        target.append(word)
    return ' '.join(target)

# evaluate the skill of the model
def evaluate_model(model, tokenizer, sources, raw_dataset):
    actual, predicted = list(), list()
    for i, source in enumerate(sources):
        # translate encoded source text
        source = source.reshape((1, source.shape[0]))
        translation = predict_sequence(model, tiv_tokenizer, source)
        raw_target, raw_src = raw_dataset[i]
        if i < 10:
            print('src=[%s], target=[%s], predicted=[%s]' % (raw_src, raw_target, translation))
        actual.append(raw_target.split())
        predicted.append(translation.split())
    # calculate BLEU score
    print('BLEU-1: %f' % corpus_bleu(actual, predicted, weights=(1.0, 0, 0, 0)))
    print('BLEU-2: %f' % corpus_bleu(actual, predicted, weights=(0.5, 0.5, 0, 0)))
    print('BLEU-3: %f' % corpus_bleu(actual, predicted, weights=(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0)))
    print('BLEU-4: %f' % corpus_bleu(actual, predicted, weights=(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25)))


# test on some training sequences
print('train')
evaluate_model(model, eng_tokenizer, trainX, train)
# test on some test sequences
print('test')
evaluate_model(model, eng_tokenizer, testX, test)
```

`

I want an interface where Users can input sentence in English and get output in Tiv language using the trained model. My presentation is coming up on Monday and I am stuck at the moment.

Comment: What's wrong with just using `sentence = input("Enter your English sentence here: ")`?

Comment: I have tried it, it seem the model wants the input to be preprocessed first.

Comment: `userInput = "i am fine" `  ` translate = model.predict(userInput)` This too never solved the problem.